# Che cosa significa "a messo" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Il paese*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Si sporse con un pacchetto molto bene confezionato e solido. – Le rincresce sporgerlo al parroco? – disse a Jeanne che s’era fatta fuori per un glimpse alla corriera.
>         – Che è?
>        – Libri, credo, – disse Eugenio.
>         – Libri!? – ironizzò il falegname. – Preservativi sono, se per il parroco. Credete a me, una grossa di preservativi –. E si schivò per non riceversi lo schiaffo di Jeanne.
>         – E perché dunque non vai mai a confessarti da lui? – obiettò Gino.
>         – È perché non ho peccati, – disse Jeanne, col pacco in mano.
>         – Peccati ne hai, se ti fai una volta al mese due colline per andarti a confessare da quel di San Rocco.
>         – Avrà un battocchio piú grosso, – disse **a messo**, senza troppo calcare.

Dovete sapere che, in questo racconto, Fenoglio scrive, di tanto in tanto, alcune parole o espressioni in inglese.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato della locuzione "a messo" in questo brano? Non l'ho trovata in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato.

Comment: Secondo me significa “disse a mezzo”, cioè a mezza voce.

Comment: Commento poco utile: è desolante vedere, cercando “a messo” con Google, vedere quante frasi ci sono del tipo “...che a messo a punto”... (e parlo di testi contemporanei, non di epoche in cui l'ortografia ancora non era stata fissata).

Comment: @DaG: Quelle horreur! (Come posso dirlo in italiano?) Forse si tratta di francesi che stanno imparando l'italiano...

Comment: @Charo Si dice comunemente *che orrore!*.

Comment: Potrebbe significare *in tono messo*.

Comment: @egreg: E cosa significa "tono messo"?

Comment: Sommesso, direi. MI suonava bene.

Comment: Adesso me n'accorgo che uno dei personaggi è un messo comunale. Quindi, potrebbe essere "disse al messo" o "disse il messo".

Comment: @Charo *Disse al messo* suona molto ragionevole. Magari è un semplice refuso (che una lettera scivoli non è poi così raro)